# Room-Temperature (or near enough) Superfluids

Tags: environment, alternate-worlds

Are there (or can there exist) a room-temperature superfluid that is not toxic or in other ways dangerous to humans? (A superfluid being a liquid that can crawl up the sides of objects and completely cover it.)

I think it would be an interesting concept, as if a lake is mostly filled with it, boats could not cross it or they would quickly fill up with fluid and sink.

Comment: Extremely unlikely, there aren't even many low-temperature superfluids in the first place. There's a lot of ambiguity as to how it actually works, so I can't rule it out, but it any decent amount of heat would ruin it. Also, it would be near-impossible to contain.

Comment: If you find one, you'll get a Nobel prize!

Comment: If someone understands more about the fluid described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.03153) you are welcome to write an answer about it.

Comment: @Zxu NOPE. Super fluids are actually quite well understood (more so than super conductors). The physics of them is actually the same as low temperature super conductors (very different from "high" temperature superconductors). Which boil (giddit?) down to Bose Einstein Condensates and Cooper Pairing.

Comment: More than superconductors is a pretty low bar.

Comment: @Zxu no, high-temp superconductors are still under study. But *conventional* superconductors is “nailed” with BCS.  That is a very high bar, understanding down to quantum details how it emerges.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The specific aspect you are looking at is *zero viscosity* while still having some surface tension.

As in the case of superconductors where something that doesn’t use [BCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCS_theory) was a surprise, you still have the normal thermal motion of the particles getting in the way of the effects you desire.

So even with *surprising* [metamaterials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial), under normal room pressure, you will still need ultracold temperatures to exhibit the [superfluid film flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4#Film_flow).

You might cheat a bit: say the unit wasn’t a large molecule but a very tiny grain of metamaterial or even a nanobot. It might show *technical* zero viscosity but still dampened out by random thermal motion; and the film creep doesn’t get very hight unless you shake the container, but once coated it stays that way.

Answer (score -1):

There are no known room temperature superfluids. So, finding non-toxic room temperature superfluids is easy. They're part of a null set of a null set. Nothing easier.

All known superfluids exist at temperatures close to absolute zero degrees Kelvin. Absolutely not, at room temperature.

JDlugosz has made the interesting suggestion that certain metamaterials might exhibit superfluid properties like zero viscosity. Metaliquids like this, are in the correct sense, metaphysics in that they belong to physics beyond the physics we know (this is the definition of metaphysics). :)

Comment: That’s not [metaphysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics) definition.  Physics beyond what we know is “physics”. What we know the physics of but cannot engineer is “known physics”.

Comment: What I was referring to was the original definition as proposed, but not necessarily in those words, by Aristotle. The meaning of metaphysics has shifted since those halycon days, by becoming more philosophical than scientific. Occasionally people need reminding where things began. The word itself "metaphysics" literally means or translates as "beyond physics", but the subject itself, these days, isn't about unknown physics and more about heavy-duty philosophy.

Comment: @a4android: The word _metaphysics_ was never used by Aristotle. The initial meaning of the word was simply "those books in the Aristotelian _Organon_ which come after the book on _Physics_".

Comment: @AlexP Thank you for the correction. What is the world coming to? A fella make a silly little joke and is jumped on everybody. Added in edit a smiley face to answer, so people can get it (hopefully).